# Android 12 - Material You icons

Tags: android, android-12

Has there been any word on how to implement Material You icons for Android 12?  Or do we just follow the old Adaptive icon guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

The closes I've come to find any documentation of this is to checkout the snapshot repository of androidx

https://androidx.dev/snapshots/builds/7844346/artifacts

I've made a repo to play around with material3's samples
Check it out: https://github.com/warting/android-material-you-sample-app